# Use retrieved data in other methods issue (AFNetworking)

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, afnetworking

I have used the `AFJSONRequest` item in my app and the data it returns in the `success` portion I want to use in other parts of the view controller. I can't for the life of me figure it out. I have created a property to hold the data but I can't access it in other methods. Any reason for this? It's probably something I'm doing wrong. How do I use the nameArray, emailArray, and passArray in other methods? They are already declared properties. Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://10.247.245.87/it/emailmanager.php"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
                                     {
                                         NSLog(@"email.last_name is of type: %@", [[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"email.lastname" ] class]);
                                         nameArray = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"email.last_name"];
                                         emailArray = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"email.email_address"];
                                         passArray = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"email.password"];
                                         NSLog(@"%@", nameArray);
                                     }
                                                                                    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON)
                                     {
                                         NSLog(@"error %@ %@", [error description], JSON);
                                     }];

[operation start];
}
```

And here is the rest.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
EMailCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EmailCell"];
cell.nameLabel.text = @"%@", nameArray;
cell.emailLabel.text = @"%@", emailArray;
cell.passLabel.text = @"%@", passArray;
return cell;

}
```

Here is the structure of the JSON results:

```
2012-11-13 07:43:46.026 IT Tools[13987:c07] Names: (
        {
    code = 0496;
    department = Management;
    "email_address" = "????@???.com";
    "first_name" = John;
    id = 227;
    "last_name" = Doe;
    password = "T0496)$(^";
    store = Toyota;
},
```

And the result from the debugger console:
`2012-11-13 09:04:37.416 IT Tools[15386:c07] email.last_name is of type: __NSArrayI`

Comment: In case it is unclear, the `nameArray` array has data when its in the `AFJSONRequestOperation` method, but in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method it is `null`. I can't figure out why. Ive tested the data returned and it was of type `NSDIctionary` but it is now saying it is `NSArray`. So there is data being returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning arrays to string values.  You should loop through the JSON results and create arrays of strings...  It would help to know the structure of your JSON results.  If you are using core data, there is a handy method for parsing JSON into core data objects.

Comment: With this being said, if I place a `NSLog` statement in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` that displays the value of the array in the debugger console, it shows `nil`. So the value it is assigned in the `AFJSONRequestOperation` isn't carrying over into the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. What do you mean by "loop through the JSON results"?

Comment: Are you using ARC?  Are you sure you have results to begin with?  Do a "NSLog(@"JSON: %@", JSON); and make sure you are receiving results from your web service.  You can check for null values in your JSON using if (![[JSON valueForKeyPath:@"email.last_name"] isMemberOfClass:[NSNull class]])

Comment: Yep I'm using ARC. I edited my answer as well. It shows I'm receiving results from the data as well.

Comment: Are you saying that you have the results in the success block, but then don't have them in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method?  Those values may be dictionaries and not arrays.  You need to do some NSLogging where you do something like:  NSLog(@"email.last_name is of type:  %@", [[JSON objectForKeyPath:@"email.last_name"] class]);  You have to find out what type of objects you are getting and use appropriately typed properties accordingly.  I think you have a type mismatch here.  Almost certainly between arrays and dictionaries.

Comment: Yes, to answer your question. Ok. I will try that. Thanks!

EDIT: I'm getting a compiler error when I use that code block:
`No known instance method for selector objectForKeyPath`

Comment: It looks as though `objectForKeyPath` isn't a valid method for JSON. I tried this:
`NSLog(@"email.last_name is of type: %@", [JSON class]);` and here is what was in the compiler:
`2012-11-13 08:03:01.662 IT Tools[14280:c07] email.last_name is of type: __NSCFDictionary` Looks like you were right!

Comment: Yes, you could use objectForKey, but you'll need to change your properties to dictionaries and act accordingly.  Please mark answer as correct.  Thanks.  Also, you'll want to use the NSDictionary or NSMutableDictionary types for your properties (not NSCFDictionary)

Comment: Well, that didn't fix the problem I had. I still cannot access those objects in other methods. Well rather I can access them, they are just `null` value. However, they aren't `null` in the `AFJSONRequestOperation` method. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know how to use arrays and dictionaries? Post your updated code.  Better yet, start a new question.  If I'm going to hold your hand through every step, we'll need to at least make a distinction between steps and issues.  Please start a new question and post your updated code.

Comment: I'm not being rude.  You were assigning arrays to dictionaries.  Now you are probably using bad syntax.  They are separate problems with separate answers, and not accepting answers after someone's helped you extensively is not good for business around here.  Again, start a new question and post your NEW code and we will be happy to help you.